# Unterschied zwischen „sich beteiligen“ und „teilnehmen“?

Tags: meaning, verb, difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *sich beteiligen* und *teilnehmen*? Die beiden bedeuten *participate*, aber werden sie in einem Satz unterschiedlich verwendet?

Answer (score 9):

***sich** beteiligen* ist im Gegensatz zu *teilnehmen* reflexiv, und es existiert sowohl das persönliche **sich** beteiligen als auch das **jemanden** beteiligen.

Weiterhin wird *beteiligen* (fast) immer mit einer Gruppe verwendet, *teilnehmen* bezieht sich meist auf eine Einzelperson

> Er nahm am Wettkampf teil
>   vs.
>   Er beteiligte sich am Projekt

Außerdem wird Teilnahme bei der emotionalen Anteilnahme an Schicksalsschlägen anderer verwendet.

> [an jemandes Glück, Freude, Leid teilnehmen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/teilnehmen)

schließlich ist teilnehmen eher das passive "am Unterricht teilnehmen" und sich beteiligen mehr aktiv im Sinne dessen, dass der sich beteiligende aktiv bei was auch immer **mitwirkt**

Comment: Man kann auch teilnehmen, ohne sich zu beteiligen, so wie man sich auch an etwas beteiligen kann, ohne daran teilzunehmen. Die Unterscheidung zwischen Gruppen/Einzelpersonen erscheint mir nicht so plausibel, das funktioniert jeweils bei beiden.

Comment: @Takkat bitte gib mir ein Beispiel für jemanden, der sich beteiligt, ohne dass eine übergeordnete Gruppe vorhanden ist, dann werde ich das gerne rausnehmen. Die Teilnahme ohne Beteiligung ist ja ein Phänomen, dass sich in der Politik doch sehr häufig zeigt: (siehe Kyoto-Protokoll, Klimagipfel, Europa, u.ä.)

Answer (score 3):

> Obwohl du teilgenommen hast, hast du dich recht wenig beteiligt.

Here

- ***teilnehmen* refers rather to the physical presence**,
- while ***beteiligen*** refers to **being actively involved** (at least cognitive).

Otherwise sometimes *teilnehmen* indicates "more" involvement. Taking the example of another answer

> Er beteiligte sich am Projekt
>
> Er nahm am Projekt teil.

I'd say that

- **in the first case** it might be **only a financial support of a project**,
- whereas **in the second case** the project seems to **require more personal dedication**.